# Thanking a professor for their effort

Tags: etiquette, professorship, email

Some time ago I had emailed a professor regarding the original data of an experiment they'd conducted almost two decades ago. He replied today to apologize as he had unfortunately not found the data after looking for it for a while.

How can I thank the professor for his efforts without coming off as condescending? Something like "Thank you very much for going to the trouble of finding the data" sounds to me like I still *expect* something and simply saying "Thank you for your effort" comes off as condescending to me, but this may be because I am not a native English speaker.

Comment: @user111388, "he had unfortunately not found the data" so the OP didn't get the data and couldn't have found it useful.

Comment: @JansthcirlU Did you mean to say "Thank you very much for going to the trouble of *looking for* the data"?

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche I forgot to mention that some of the data was publicly availably in an article, which was insightful. Unfortunately I have already sent the email but you're right, I should've rephrased my first sentence.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche: O, f*ck, my mistake. Sorry.

Comment: I'll note that some of us who _are_ native English speakers have difficulty with such things at times.

Comment: This question is about English language rather than academia.  Consider the English Language Learners site.

Comment: While I agree that the English Learners forum may be more useful for these types of formulation issues, I was mainly trying to get the opinions of professors or the opinions of people in academia who may have found themselves in a situation similar to mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be fine to simply write

"Dear Professor X,

Thank you for taking the time to look.

Best wishes,

JansthcirlU"

Comment: I'd add _very much_ after thank you ;-)

Comment: Yes, this is enough, though the suggestion by @MassimoOrtolano is a good one. Simple. Direct.